# Need help with sending variables into a function PHP

Tags: php, payment-processing, webshop

I am working on a webshop and need help to get an iDeal plugin (payment methode from the Netherlands) working.

I need to send through the amount (price) of the items that need to be payed for.
I get the quantity of the items from the previous page like this

```
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
```

and make a total price variable like this  (2999 is the price, it needs to be in cents so the price is 29,99)

```
$totaalprijs = 2999 * $qty;
$iAmount = $totaalprijs;
```

the visitor choses his bank and initiates the payment by pressing on a submit button
then this happens

```
$oIdeal->setIdealAmount ( $iAmount );
```

It is sending the variable to this function in another php file, checks if the value is numeric of not 0 and send it through to the payment method via another function.

```
public function setIdealAmount ( $intIdealAmount ) {

  # Is this a valid ideal amount?
  if ( is_numeric ( $intIdealAmount ) && $intIdealAmount > 0 ) {
    $this->idealAmount = $intIdealAmount;    
  }
  else {
    throw new Exception( 'Invalid ideal amount, please check.' );   
  }
   return $this;
```

}

And here is the problem, when its send through the function it always returns 0 
except when I for example do this:

```
$iAmount = 2999;
```

I want the total price of the items to be price * qty but it only returns $this when I declare my $iAmount variable like above.

The error message i get is this:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid ideal amount, please check.' in /home/spraytanning-express.nl/www/TargetPayIdeal.class.php:154 Stack trace: #0 /home/spraytanning-express.nl/www/betalen.php(116): TargetPayIdeal->setIdealAmount(0) #1 {main} thrown in /home/spraytanning-express.nl/www/TargetPayIdeal.class.php on line 154`

Hopefully some of you can help me...
And by the way, sorry for my bad english :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you 100% sure that something is being set in $_POST['qty']?  If nothing is set there, 0 will be the default which could cause this behavior.

Comment: yes there is when i var_dump($totaalprijs) it returns for example int(5998) when i have 2 products added to my cart

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting up your check and explicitly throwing exceptions based on which check failed:

```
public function setIdealAmount ( $intIdealAmount ) {
    var_dump($intIdealAmount); // see what the value is
    if (!is_numeric($intIdealAmount)) {
           throw new Exception( 'ideal amount not numeric' );   
    }
    if ($intIdealAmount <= 0) {
        throw new Exception('ideal amount <= 0');
    }
    etc...
}
```

Right now your exception is somewhat useful to show something's wrong, but is useless to explain exactly why something's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

But in my question i allready statet that it returned as 0..
I tried your function and it came out with the message 
ideal amount <= 0

Comment: So do a `var_dump($_POST['qty'])` and make sure you're actually getting something from your form, then duplicate down the line as you manipulate the value. Find out where the value gets zeroed out and there's your bug.

Comment: Ok i tried that, and it returns 0 when i send it from
$oIdeal->setIdealAmount ( $iAmount );
(Beneath that function it is still working and also is an int())

So when i send it from one page to the setIdealAmount function on another page, it returns 0 when it goes through that function..

How can i fix that? 

Sorry i am really bad at php :$

Comment: Ok, so your form isn't submitting the value properly. check that there is a `qty` field in it, etc...

Comment: no it is, when i var_dump($totaalprijs) it returns int(5998) when i add 2 products to my cart.. so there is not the problem.

Comment: Oh. multiple pages? you'd need to make sure you're using the correct request method. _POST is only populated if you actually are doing a POST method request (e.g. via a form). php defaults to using GET (and $_GET) otherwise.

Comment: So the variable gets lost when i call the $oIdeal->setIdealAmount ($iAmount); and sends it through too that function setIdealAmount()

Comment: Yes the flow is like this:   the visitor adds products to cart and goes to checkout page -> in the checkout page there is a hidden form that sends the qty, title, price etc.. to another page (this is an overview of the cart and the visitor can select his bank..

when he selects his bank then the $oIdeal->setIdealAmount( $iAmount) is called..

and if the amount returns in a good way without errors it gets send through to the bank

Comment: So when i do this $iAmount = 2999; instead of  $totaalprijs = 299 * $qty; and $iAmount = $totaalprijs  it send it through to the bank without any problems

Answer (score 0):

If you're not already doing it, you may need to initialize the $idealAmount variable before referring to it with the $this-> object.  Also, you may want to do a check that $_POST['qty'] is numeric.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
the variable $totaalprijs returns as int when i dump the var..
and the problem is not at the $idealAmount..